# Taxonomy menu - link to first node associated with term?

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy menu block using the vocabulary 'Projects' that links to the terms: 'Bridges', 'Buildings' and 'Boats'.

Currently, each menu item links to a page that lists teasers of all the nodes associated with the menu term. For example, I click on 'Buildings' and it goes to a page with teasers of all nodes associated with 'Buildings'.

How could I have the menu term link to the latest node associated with that term directly? To continue the example, I click on 'Buildings' and it takes me to the latest 'Buildings' node.

The list of teasers is unnecessary as I will be employing elements of the teasers in an aside on each node directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out; here's the solution in case anyone else needs this functionality.

Forget the Taxonomy Menu module. We'll build the functionality with a view.

1. Make a taxonomy term view (under Show when creating a view).
2. Under Advanced, add this Relationship: Taxonomy Term - Representative Node. 
   You can leave all the settings the same, but I suggest checking 'Require this
   relationship' so empty terms will not get linked
3. Also Under Advanced, change Use aggregation to Yes
4. Add a filter for Taxonomy Vocabulary (with whatever vocab you want)
5. Add a Content:Path field, exclude it from display and check 'Use absolute link'
6. Add a Taxonomy Term:Name field and check Output this field as a link. For the Link Path use the Path Replacement Pattern from the Path field we just added (usually [path]).